# Showing posts with upvote count higher than 500 - Meteor

Tags: meteor

My current code below gets only 5 highest voted posts, showing the one with highest votes on top. What I want to do is, don't limit the post amount and only show posts with upvote count higher than 500. I want to sort them like, lowest voted post on top.

```
Template.top.helpers({
    posts: function () {
      return Posts.find({}, {sort: {votes: -1}, limit: 5});
    }
});
```

PS: If this requires additional work besides the code above, any hints on how to proceed is well appreciated. The project is something I work on just to learn.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```js
Template.top.helpers({
    posts: function () {
      return Posts.find({votes: {$gte: 500}}, {sort: {votes: 1}});
    }
});
```

It uses [$gte](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/) to select the posts with votes >= 500.

Comment: It didn't work at first but then I realised the missing "}". Awesome! Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks! Another question though. What if I wanted to show posts with vote count between 500 and 1000? Is that something simple? Just asking out of curiosity to learn one more thing

Comment: Yep, you can just use `{votes: {$gte: 500, $lte: 1000}}` as your selector.